How to preserve input and output values when adding new tabs?
I'm encountering a peculiar issue when developing my Python shiny app. My app currently has the functionality to dynamically generate new tabs with the press of a navset tab called "+". However, after pressing "+", the state (including input and output values) of the previous tabs reset back to empty. Is there a way to preserve the state of any previously existing tabs?
My code is outlined below:
from shiny import App, Inputs, Outputs, Session, module, reactive, render, ui

# Create a Module UI
@module.ui
def textbox_ui(panelNum):
    return ui.nav_panel(
        f"Tab {panelNum}",
        ui.input_text_area(id=f"test_text",
                           label = "Enter some text"),
        ui.output_ui(f"display_text_{panelNum}"),
        value = f"Tab_{panelNum}"
    )

# Set up module server
@module.server
def textbox_server(input, output, session, panelNum):

    @output(id=f"display_text_{panelNum}")
    @render.text
    def return_text():
       return input[f"test_text"]()


# Set up app UI
app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.tags.head(
       ui.tags.style(
           """
           body {
               height: 100vh;
               overflow-y: auto !important;
           }
           """
       )
    ),
    ui.h2('Test App', align='center', fillable=True),
    ui.output_ui("tab_UI"),
    title = "Test App"
)

# Set up server
def server(input, output, session):
   
   # Set up reactive values
   navs = reactive.value(0)
   
   # Add tabs if the user presses "+"
   @reactive.effect
   @reactive.event(input.shiny_tabs)
   def add_tabs():
      if input.shiny_tabs() == "+":
          navs.set(navs.get() + 1)
   
   @output
   @render.ui
   def tab_UI():
      [textbox_server(str(x), panelNum=x+1) for x in range(navs.get())]
      ui.update_navs("shiny_tabs", selected = f"Tab_{navs.get()}")

      return ui.navset_tab(
         ui.nav_panel("Home",
                      ui.card(
                         ui.card_header("Overview"),
                         ui.p("An example of the outputs clearing")
                         ),
                      value = "panel0"
                      ),
        *[textbox_ui(str(x), panelNum=x+1) for x in range(navs.get())],
        ui.nav_panel("+"),
        id = "shiny_tabs"
     )

app = App(app_ui, server)


Your code has several bugs and the problem is not reproducible. 1) There are several commas missing and 2) if I insert all of them and click the + button I get the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resolve'. Edit your question and provide a minimal, reproducible example, in particular test it before posting it here.

@Jan Apologies for the errors on my part. You are correct. There were commas missing throughout my example that are now fixed via editing. Let me know if there are still issues. Thank you for looking into it.

Thanks a lot. However, I still have the other problem. If I click on the + button, I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resolve', it crashes. Could you please check this?

@Jan I can't believe I never included the "return" in my textbox_ui function. Edited and fixed. It should be reproducible now. Again really sorry about that mix up.

The reason for the reset is that the navset_tab is re-rendered each time a new nav_panel gets appended. So an approach would be better where we have the navset_tab outside of the server and then append a nav_panel on click without re-rendering everything.
The difficulty is on the one hand that ui.insert_ui does not seem to be suitable for the insert and on the other hand that Shiny for Python currently does not carry functions for dynamic navs, see e.g. posit-dev/py-shiny#089.
However, within the PR#90 is a draft for an insert function nav_insert which is suitable for this application. I adapted this below and re-wrote your app, we now only insert a new tab if the button is clicked, the rest stays stable.

import sys
from shiny import App, reactive, ui, Session, Inputs, Outputs, module, render
from shiny._utils import run_coro_sync
from shiny._namespaces import resolve_id
from shiny.types import NavSetArg
from shiny.session import require_active_session
from typing import Optional, Union

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from typing import Literal
else:
    from typing_extensions import Literal

# adapted from https://github.com/posit-dev/py-shiny/pull/90/files
def nav_insert(
    id: str,
    nav: Union[NavSetArg, str],
    target: Optional[str] = None,
    position: Literal["after", "before"] = "after",
    select: bool = False,
    session: Optional[Session] = None,
) -> None:

    """
    Insert a new nav item into a navigation container.
    Parameters
    ----------
    id
        The ``id`` of the relevant navigation container (i.e., ``navset_*()`` object).
    nav
        The navigation item to insert (typically a :func:`~shiny.ui.nav` or
        :func:`~shiny.ui.nav_menu`). A :func:`~shiny.ui.nav_menu` isn't allowed when the
        ``target`` references an :func:`~shiny.ui.nav_menu` (or an item within it). A
        string is only allowed when the ``target`` references a
        :func:`~shiny.ui.nav_menu`.
    target
        The ``value`` of an existing :func:`shiny.ui.nav` item, next to which tab will
        be added. Can also be ``None``; see ``position``.
    position
        The position of the new nav item relative to the target nav item. If
        ``target=None``, then ``"before"`` means the new nav item should be inserted at
        the head of the navlist, and ``"after"`` is the end.
    select
        Whether the nav item should be selected upon insertion.
    session
        A :class:`~shiny.Session` instance. If not provided, it is inferred via
        :func:`~shiny.session.get_current_session`.
   
    """
    
    session = require_active_session(session)

    li_tag, div_tag = nav.resolve(
        selected=None, context=dict(tabsetid="tsid", index="id")
    )

    msg = {
        "inputId": resolve_id(id),
        "liTag": session._process_ui(li_tag),
        "divTag": session._process_ui(div_tag),
        "menuName": None,
        "target": target,
        "position": position,
        "select": select,
    }

    def callback() -> None:
        run_coro_sync(session._send_message({"shiny-insert-tab": msg}))

    session.on_flush(callback, once=True)
    
@module.ui
def textbox_ui(panelNum):
    return ui.nav_panel(
        f"Tab {panelNum}",
        ui.input_text_area(id=f"test_text_{panelNum}",
                           label = "Enter some text"),
        ui.output_ui(f"display_text_{panelNum}"),
        value = f"Tab_{panelNum}"
    )
    
@module.server
def textbox_server(input, output, session, panelNum):

    @output(id=f"display_text_{panelNum}")
    @render.text
    def return_text():
        return input[f"test_text_{panelNum}"]()
    
app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.tags.head(
       ui.tags.style(
           """
           body {
               height: 100vh;
               overflow-y: auto !important;
           }
           """
       )
    ),
    ui.h2('Test App', align='center', fillable=True),
    ui.navset_tab(
         ui.nav_panel("Home",
                      ui.card(
                         ui.card_header("Overview"),
                         ui.p("An example of the outputs not clearing")
                         ),
                      value = "Tab_0"
                      ),
        ui.nav_panel("+"),
        id = "shiny_tabs"
    ),
    title = "Test App"
)

def server(input: Inputs, output: Outputs, session: Session):
    
    navCounter = reactive.value(0)
    
    @reactive.effect
    @reactive.event(input.shiny_tabs)
    def add_tabs():
        if input.shiny_tabs() == "+":
            navCounter.set(navCounter.get() + 1)
           
            id = str(navCounter.get())
            idPrev = str(navCounter.get() - 1)
            nav_insert(
                "shiny_tabs",
                textbox_ui(id, id),
                target=f"Tab_{idPrev}",
                position="after",
                select=True
            )
            
            textbox_server(id, id)

app = App(app_ui, server)


Brilliantly done @Jan! Thank you so much. I had seen this raised as an issue in their Github but never would've thought to make a custom adaptation. This is fantastic.
